# error with user-defined function in kusto query

Tags: azure, kql

I tried to run below query as user-defined function in kusto but always gives me an error. can someone help me to understand what i am missing here? When i run the query seprately it works but i want to use it like a function as i want to call it separately for every month and union the results .

```
let availability = (starttime:datetime   , endtime:datetime )
{

//let month = format_datetime(starttime,"yyyy-M-dd");
Heartbeat
//| where TimeGenerated >= startofweek(ago(21d
| where TimeGenerated > starttime and TimeGenerated < endtime
| where ResourceId !=""
| summarize heartbeat_per_hour=count() by bin_at(TimeGenerated, 1h, starttime), Computer
| extend available_per_hour=iff(heartbeat_per_hour>0, true, false)
| summarize total_available_hours=countif(available_per_hour==true) by Computer 
| extend total_number_of_buckets=round((endtime-starttime)/1h)
| extend availability_rate=total_available_hours*100/total_number_of_buckets
//| extend month

};

let starttime = startofday(datetime("2020-09-01 00:00:00 AM"));
let endtime = endofday(datetime("2020-09-30 11:59:59 PM"));
availability(starttime,endtime)
```

Comment: "*...but always gives me an error.*": i would recommend you include the error message. plus, make sure you're familiar with Restrictions that apply to user-defined functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#restrictions